# COUNTIFS in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to perform an MS Excel COUNTIFS in Pandas?

I have a dataframe containing 4 columns as follows:

```
 project_number        crew1        crew2 crew3
0           V58615          EWP         None  None
1           V58615          EWP  Ground Line  None
2           V58615          EWP      Chipper  None
3           V58615          EWP      Chipper  None
4           V58615  Ground Line         None  None
```

Then I have another one which is a summary of all the Project Numbers. Is there any way I can perform the equivalent of a COUNTIFS that would calculate how many times EWP would correspond to the value V58615 if that value was contained in another summary list? The issue that I seem to be having is basing values that span more than 1 column. Performing this task on values in a single column in a for loop using if can be achieved, but anything that goes beyond becomes difficult
Below is how I attempted to calculate this:

```
project_numbers = np.array(vma_list.loc[:, 'Project Number'])
crews = konect_outstanding_tasks[['project_number', 'crew1', 'crew2', 
'crew3']]
 print(vma_list['Project Number'])
 l = np.where(crews == 'EWP',1,0)

 def equipment(crew):
   if crew == 'ewp':
      for x, y in enumerate(crews):
        vma_list.loc[x:, 'EWP'] = np.sum(np.where(crews[y] == 'EWP',1,0))
        print(vma_list)
```

As you can see there are a number of reasons as to why that failed; it returns an aggregate sum, but does not summerise as if performed in Excel using a combination of SUM and COUNTIF

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) first:

```
df = konect_outstanding_tasks[['project_number', 'crew1', 'crew2', 'crew3']]

df1 = df.melt('project_number', var_name='a', value_name='v').dropna(subset=['v'])
print (df1)
  project_number      a            v
0         V58615  crew1          EWP
1         V58615  crew1          EWP
2         V58615  crew1          EWP
3         V58615  crew1          EWP
4         V58615  crew1  Ground Line
6         V58615  crew2  Ground Line
7         V58615  crew2      Chipper
8         V58615  crew2      Chipper
```

And then counts per groups by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['project_number','v']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df2)
  project_number            v  count
0         V58615      Chipper      2
1         V58615          EWP      4
2         V58615  Ground Line      2
```

If need only `ewp` values first compare by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
ewp = df1['v'].eq('EWP').sum()
print (ewp)
4
```

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mind, could you please provide a brief explanation of how that works, as the code I attempted to use was far more complex and simply failed

Comment: @jasw - Can you be more specific, what failed? Created `df1` like in my data?

Comment: jezrael your solution basically replicated COUNTIF

Comment: @jasw - Can you add expected output from data?

Comment: @jasw - Answer was edited, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60333540/revisions)

Comment: the script needs to calculate how many times a resource value (EWP in this case) corresponds to a project_number based on the project_number in another dataframe. So in order for this to function, in df1, the project_number and v columns would act as crietria ranges and values EWP and the V58615 would act as the criteria value only if the value V58615 was in the list of project_numbers contained with the vma_list. Does this make sense?

Comment: in MS Excel this type of calculation can be performed over multiple tabs using COUNTIFS, but this is becoming quite slow due to the size of the dataset. Note that the data that I am using and evaluating is a csv file that is a direct dump from another database

Comment: @jasw Yop, but I still not understnad why my solution not working for you, because with sample data working perfectly. for you resturn different outputs? How looks exactly output from sample data in numbers, I dont need describe it, only I want to see numbers in Dataframe for verify my solution. thanks.